# Adding a side nav bar is not showing the menu items

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a side nav drawer to my flutter app.

I can add the drawer but none of the menu items show up in the drawer. The only thing that shows up is the text "User Profile".

Here is the code for the main screen where I add the drawer to the screen:

```
class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const SideMenu(),
      body: Container(child: appScreens[_pageIndex]),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = value;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined), label: "Trxn"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: "Calendar"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "User"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: 'Chat'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  void setIndex(int index) {
    if (mounted) setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
  }
}
```

Here is the SideMenu class code:

```
class SideMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const SideMenu({super.key});

  @override
  State<SideMenu> createState() => _SideMenuState();
}

class _SideMenuState extends State<SideMenu> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const CompanyScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: (ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: const Text('Billy Bob Baker'),
            accountEmail: const Text('billy.bob.baker@gmail.com'),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              child: ClipOval(child: Image.asset('images/image.jpg')),
            ),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Home'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 0,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(0);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('New Transaction'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 1,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(1);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Appointments'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 2,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(2);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Add Company'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 3,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(3);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Add User'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 4,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(4);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Chat'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 5,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(5);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Log Out'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 6,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(2);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I am following this example to make the SidMenu class: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer

How do I get the menu items to show up?
Thanks

Comment: What does the code for `UserAccountsDrawerHeader`look like? What happens when you remove it?

Comment: Thanks for you response. UserAccountDrawerHeader is a class and the documentation can be found here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/UserAccountsDrawerHeader-class.html    I removed it from my code but nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks, today I learned that's a builtin class.

Comment: I removed the photo and it started working.